# How to represent a process made by two departments in a cross functional flowchart?

Tags: flowchart

In my flowchart I have:

- Department A
- Department B
- Department C

So then, let´s think I need to `process 1` be made by `department A` & `department B`.
What would be the correct way to represent that into a cross functional flowchart?
I were looking in internet but I could not find anything useful.
So I start thinking and I tried some drafts:

Draft 1:In this flowchart, I locate `process 1` in the middle of both lanes.
[image: draft1]

Draft 2: In this way, I clone `process 1` in both lanes (Department A & Department B)
[image: drraft2]

I hope you can help me with that. As you can see I am proposing some options that could work. Maybe they are not correct, but I am still trying. Thanks in advance.